# How to display the result value outside the axes box

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I plotted the picture using the code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(6)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

for i in xrange(5):
    ax.set_xlim(0, 3)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
    ax.plot(x, i * x)

plt.show()
```

This is the result picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWCJl.png)

This is the picture I want to see.
I want to get the results out of the box area.
How can you draw such a plot?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FGII.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(6)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

for i in xrange(5):
    ax.set_xlim(0, 3)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
    ax.plot(x, i * x)
    if 3*i >10:
        ytx = 10.5
        xtx = 10.0/i
    else:
        ytx = 3*i
        xtx = 3.05
    tx = plt.text(xtx, ytx, str(i), fontsize=18, color='black')

plt.show()
```

This generates -

[image]